# Bootstrap tooltip hiding inside iframe

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, tooltip

I have an Iframe. In right most corner I have an icon to which i have tooltip. But the last part are hiding. It is showing only till the width of the iframe.

Is there any way to show that above iframe

I tried `z-index` and `data-container="body"` but not working.

Or is there any way to show bootstrap tooltip to start from right most corner. ie (`data-placement="top-right"`) like that possible ?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="link-body">
    <span>
        <span class="link" style="display:none">Link</span>
    </span>

    <input id="link" class="form-control" readonly />
    <div class="form-control" readonly="" data-original-title="Click here"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code, what you are working so far

Comment: Where is iframe, icon and css? can you provide some more information or create a jsfiddle. that will be more useful for us.